# How do I move an item to a folder with the keyboard in the outlook.com beta?

Tags: outlook.com, keyboard-shortcuts

I just joined the new [outlook.com beta](https://blogs.office.com/en-us/2017/08/08/introducing-the-outlook-com-beta/), and I used to be able to press "v" to move an item to a folder, but I can't find any keyboard shortcut to do this.

Does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently keyboard shortcuts aren't fully implemented yet:

> Thanks for your feedback on the Outlook.com beta! Yes, full support for keyboard shortcuts is coming in a future update. - Lynn Ayres from Outlook

[From the Outlook.com beta UserVoice](https://outlook.uservoice.com/forums/601444-outlook-com-beta/suggestions/20477521-keyboard-shortcuts-not-working)